# Putting a RLE image in my kernel

Tags: android, linux, boot, boot-animation

Have an rle image
putting this rle image in device/myv200/v200/overlay/initlogo
Now I am booting again, why this image is not showing?

Comment: Please go through [it](http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1731272/) once.

Comment: is this the only way?

Comment: I thought so, wait for a day if you don't get any answer follow that.

Comment: Actually its not a developer friendly way, because the out folder is already created.

Comment: I know but there not other way I can remind.

Comment: i have created a rle image, now what to do. i have unpacked the ramdisk. do i have to put that rle image in extracted ramdisk and then unpack it.

Comment: follow the steps in that tutorial only